# How to loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, file-management

I have a directory that contains files like:

```
PropertyNameRevCount.pdf
PropertyNameRevWordcloud.pdf
PropertyNameRevComments.pdf
```

I'm trying to move them into a subdirectory of the current directory with the name:

```
PropertyName
```

I already have the directories made and have hundreds of files I need to move. I'm looking for a bash Script to help automate the process. I have this so far:

```
For f in *.pdf
```

I just don't know how to get only the first part of the file name to be the condition for movement.

Comment: I presume `PropertyName` is just a placeholder and might change? Do they all have `Rev` at the end of the first part?

Comment: Yes PropertyName is a place holder. There are several of them ex. PropertyName1, PropertyName2, etc. They unfortunately do not all have Rev, some will have TALi

Comment: So how to identify this 'first part'?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I just want a way to identify the first part

Comment: I mean, what common characteristic identifies the 'first part'? A fixed number of characters? A delimiter such as an underscore etc at the end? Something else? We cannot read your mind.

Comment: Sorry, I generate the pdf files from R Studio so I can put an underscore there if that makes it easier.

Comment: So edit your question to include some specimen real-life file names

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple loop:

```
for FILE in PropertyName*.pdf
do
    mv $FILE PropertyName
done
```

A more complex example, assuming I have a list of valid PropertyNames and a list of valid 'SecondParts'

```
for FILE in {PropertyName1,PropertyName2,PropertyName3}*.pdf
do if [ -e $FILE ]
then
    DIR=`echo $FILE|sed -E -e 's/(Rev|TALi).pdf$//'`
    mv $FILE $DIR
fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for this, is there a way to do this for several PropertyNames?

Comment: Do you know in advance how to identify a valid PropertyName?  If so, how?

Comment: Alternatively, do you know in advance what the extra 'second part' would be?  Is it only Rev and Tali?

Comment: Tip: use a slash at the end of your directory. I.e. `mv $FILE PropertyName/`. Why? Typo protection.  If you instead did `mv $FILE PropetyName` you’ve just renamed a bunch of files to the same file name, meaning only the last one in the list is still around, and you can’t get the others back.

Comment: @MarcusArmstrong do a “help extglob” in bash, it may help you match better.

Comment: The only endings will ever be Rev and TALi and yes I have a text file with all the property names in it which I use to create the PropertyName folders. I also create the PDF files in an R program and can add a delimiter like an underscore if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` to split a string on a delimiter, for example an underscore

```
fname="applebox_businesstruck.pdf"
firstpart=$(cut -d_ -f1 <<< "$fname")
echo $firstpart
applebox
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding of your question & solution for the same

Your current directory tree as below

```
|-- AnotherProp
|-- AnotherProptell.pdf
|-- AnotherProptest.pdf
|-- AnotherProptouch.pdf
|-- PropName
|-- PropNametell.pdf
|-- PropNametest.pdf
`-- PropNametouch.pdf
```

You're looking to move pdf file to appropriate subdirectory based on the first part of your file name ?

BASH script to be as follows (**MoveMyFiles.sh**) -

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    #Read all the subdirectory names in your current directory
    subdirs=( $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%P\n" ))
    
    # Loop1 - Read all the files
    for file in *.pdf
    do
        #Loop2 - Match filename with subdirectory
        for mydir in ${subdirs[@]}
        do
            [[ ${file} =~ ^$mydir.* ]] && echo "move $file to $mydir"
        done
    done
```

**Sample Output as -**

```
move AnotherProptell.pdf to AnotherProp
move AnotherProptest.pdf to AnotherProp
move AnotherProptouch.pdf to AnotherProp
move PropNametell.pdf to PropName
move PropNametest.pdf to PropName
move PropNametouch.pdf to PropName
```

In the Loop2, echo statement can be replaced with a function or mv command based on your requirement.

Hope this helps.